# Akhq UI shows Consumer lag always 1 for jdbc sink connector even though all messages are consumed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

we are using Kafka stream(2.5.0 jar) with the java application ( with exactly once semantics) and a Jdbc sink connector (UPSERT mode)  to write data to db.

*flow:-*

Java Kafka Stream app -------- >  Db Sink Connector.

the akhq user interface shows a lag of 1 always ,even though all are valid messages. All the messages are consumed.  is it due to the connector is not having "isolation.level" as "read_committed" ,currently "read_uncommited". The lag is shown in the pic below. Also I have seen
a bug  related to Kafka https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10683 ,is it related to this.

[Sink connector consumer lag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpyTT.png)

Comment: @OneCricketeer: you have any idea on this?

Comment: I think the JIRA you found is the likely issue, at least if the producer is indeed using a  transactional producer

Comment: @OneCricketeer: ok .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late question but I don't know people ask question about akhq on stackoverflow.

It's a behaviour of Kafka Transaction.
Kafka transaction are handle with a commit message that will never be read by a Kafka Consumer.
The consumer just can't know that last offset is a commit.
So as Akhq is a simple Kafka consumer, it will be always see this lag of 1.

You will have this for every application using Kafka transaction.