# Kafka Sink Connector lags always show 1 even after processing all records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka connect.
I am using a Kafka Sink Connector to write data to a datalake. The connector writes the data to a staging location and then moves it to the target location. However, when it processes all the data in the topic, and I check the lags in Kafka Manager, it always shows 1 if there is no data in the topic and it has processed all the records. It doesn’t go to 0.
When there is data in topic again then lag becomes greater as expected and in sometime it comes down to 1 again after processing the records.
Here is the config which I am using:

```
"config": {
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "xxx",
    "adls.endpoint": "xxxx",
    "adls.container.name": "xxxx",
    "adls.auth.method": "ClientSecret",
    "adls.tenant.id": "xxxx",
    "adls.client.id": "xxxx",
    "adls.client.secret": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "base.directory": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "rotation.filesize" : "1000000000",
    "rotation.inactivity" : "1800000",
    "rotation.record.count" : "100000",
    "auto.offset.reset":"earliest",
   "commit.rotated.only":false
  }
```

I would like to understand how to bring the lag to zero, as it’s triggering an alert for me when the lag remains at 1 for a longer period of time.
I am not facing any data consistency issues, and I am receiving all the records. I would like to know what the best practice is to follow in this case. Is it possible to bring the lag to zero, or should I modify my alerting?
I am not aware of the internal code implementation for this sink connector. I am using a JAR file.

I am using configurations from here :

[LINK OF CONNECTOR CONFIGURATIONS](https://docs.axual.io/connect/Axual-Connect/developer/connect-plugins-catalog/plugins-made-by-axual/adls-gen2-sink/configuring.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly based on the provided config, but it could be due to Kafka transactions. There is a known issue that when using Kafka transactions, the consumer lag never reaches 0, due to the last message being a commit message, that will not be read by the consumer.

[Consumer.position() Ignores Transaction Marker with read_uncommitted](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10683)

And a related answer

[Akhq UI shows Consumer lag always 1 for jdbc sink connector even though all messages are consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67966228/akhq-ui-shows-consumer-lag-always-1-for-jdbc-sink-connector-even-though-all-mess)

I would suggest changing your alerting to when consumer lag is > 1 to account for this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated the question to include the link to the configurations that I am using. It contains details of connector configuration.


Additionally, I wanted to mention that I have noted your observation regarding the pseudo-lag issue. It seems to occur only for connectors that write to ADLS Gen2, while it does not occur for connectors that write to ADLS Gen1 or Snowflake.